# Why 1*2+3 is parsed as 1*(2+3) even though operator precedence or associativity is not declared?

Tags: parsing, yacc, fsyacc

I use fsyacc (yacc for fsharp) to write a small parser. The grammar is something like

```
Expr:=
  | INT                              { Cst $1           }  
  | Expr PLUS  Expr                     { Op("+", $1, $3) }  
  | Expr TIMES Expr                     { Op("*", $1, $3) }
```

Then, without declaring precedence or associativity, I got "1*2+3" parsed as

```
Op ("*",Cst 1,Op ("+",Cst 2,Cst 3)
```

Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't declare a precedence and associativity for your tokens in an ambiguous grammar such as you describe, by default yacc will resolve the resulting shift/reduce conflict in favor if the shift.  This has the effect of making the rule right recursive, so the operators will appear to group right to left.

If you *do* define precedence rules, what they do is to resolve shift/reduce conflicts in favor of the higher precedence (token or rule) or, if the same precedence, in favor of shift for `%right` and reduce for `%left`.  That's basically all that the precedence settings do, so they can sometimes be used to resolve conflicts in a way that has nothing really to do with "precedence" if that is what you want to do.  But for a simple infix expression grammar, they basically do exactly what you want.